# Rollback data in integration environment after every test

Tags: java, oracle, automated-tests, integration-testing, rollback

We have a legacy system that uses Java and an Oracle database.

I now want to set up an integration environment where we can run tests through HTTP calls.

Before the whole cycle of tests starts the database would be set up anew. We already have a functionality for this.

Now after every test only the modified data from this test should be rolled back. Is this somehow possible on an Oracle database?

Comment: what do you mean 'doesn't use database transactions'?  How can you use a database without it?

Comment: I don't understand: you have a procedure to set up your database "anew", but... it doesn't?

Comment: @kevinsky Maybe I was wrong about the transactions and phrased my question the wrong way. Let's say before the test I have state A on my database. Then after a test I have state B. But after every test state A should be restored again.

Comment: @Mat Our database set up drops some schemas and creates the tables. But I don't want to use this functionality after every this. After each test only the state before the test should be restored.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Oracle 11 you can use the [FLASHBACK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9012.htm#SQLRF01802) command to restore a table to a point in time.  Usage is like this

```
FLASHBACK TABLE employees_test
  TO TIMESTAMP (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' minute);
```

Your user will need special privileges

- SELECT ANY DICTIONARY or FLASHBACK ANY TABLE or the SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE

I assume this is for a development or test instance as these privileges are not allowed to all users on production.

Answer (score 0):

Two options I see for this:

- [Flashback database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/flashdb.htm#BRADV71000) - you can do a sort of global "rollback" of your database to a predefined restore point.
- Use [Datapump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL936): when your schema is ready, export it. After each test, import it with `CONTENT=DATA_ONLY` and `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=TRUNCATE` (for example). Can be fairly fast, doesn't require setting things up for flashback.